# how to use simple getter and setter with android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, getter-setter, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a class country with an arraylist that stores countries. I have created a get and set to add and get items from specified indexes from the array list but i wont work. Whenever i call an index from the arraylist i get an out of bounds exception because the array is empty or at least seems to be.

```
public class country extends Application {

    public ArrayList<country> countryList = new ArrayList<country>();
    public String Name;
    public String Code;
    public String  ID;

    public country()
    {

    }

    public country(String name, String id, String code)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ID = id;
        this.Code = code;
    }

    public void setCountry(country c)
    {
        countryList.add(c);
    }

    public country getCountry(int index)
    {   
        country aCountry = countryList.get(index);
        return aCountry;
    }
```

to call the setter i use. i do this inside a for loop so it adds 200+ elements

```
country ref = new country();

ref.setCountry(new country (sName, ID, Code));
```

then when i want to get an index

```
String name = ref.countryList.get(2).Name;
```

i have done the same thing but used a local arraylist and it populated fine and i was able to display the names so the datasource isnt the problem its whatever im doing wrong setting and getting the data inside the arraylist in the country class

Comment: the local arraylist which gets created along with the country arraylist contains 200+ objects so thats not the problemm.

                           resultbox.setText(countryNames.get(2).Name); // prints a name
                           resultbox.setText(ref.getCountry(2).Name); //returns error

Comment: Do ref.countryList.get(0).Name as you have added only 1 item into the list;

Comment: Show us the code that adds the 200+ objects. You are most likely adding it to a different list.

Answer (score 0):

You access a non-existing index. You only add one country ergo you can only access:

```
String name = ref.countryList.get(0).Name;
```

And you should really rethink your design. `public` attributes are not the best-practice way. This is the reason why you should write getter and setter methods in the first place.

You should do something like this instead:

```
public Country getCountry(int index)
{
    if(index < countryList.size())
    {
        return countryList.get(index);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `String name = ref.countryList.get(2).Name;` you are trying to get the **third** element in the list while you added only **one**...
it should be `String name = ref.countryList.get(0).Name;` and you need to check before for not receiving null pointer exception

Comment: i updated my comment above but i use a for loop so there should be way more than 3 items in the arraylist. the local version contains 241

Answer (score -1):

Do `ref.countryList.get(0).Name` as you have added only 1 item into the list.

I would suggest more of it like

```
 ref.countryList.get(0).getName()
```

Comment: no there should be 200+ items in the list i use a for loop to add them all. the local version of the arraylist which i made for testing has 241 items inside of it and i do the same thing to add to both

Comment: Then I dont think there is any reason for exception , Can you post your exception stacktrace

Comment: com.example.wsdl1.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:95)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: you said you were getting outofbound exception.. I dont see that here

Comment: thats what appears in logcat. When i output the message to the screen i get out of bounds. i updated the code daniel posted and now i get a nullpointerexception but its the same thing

Comment: See, when you get a nullpointerexception..m there must be a line no. mentioned in the stack. So if you try to find out that line no. we can see which line is giving an error. Or else is there some way I could get all your code and try to run on my side. Because just with the code that you have posted , it is working fine for me

Comment: There is one more possibility of error , that the code you are running has old .class files, you can try by deleting those .class files and compile your classes again.

Comment: i have through trial and error found the line thats breaking it is resultbox.setText(ref.getCountry(0).Name); when this line is gone it doesnt throw an exception but also doesnt give a result. but i know its giving the exception because there isnt anything inside of the array. Perhaps its worth mentioning that the adding of the data to the arraylist is done inside of a thread. But i dont see how that is the problem as i have the same code side by side 1 is adding to the local arraylist and and other to country arraylist. 1 works the other doesnt

Comment: Dude I seriously need to see completely code to solve this mistery.